# The LED bulb in my room has written 9 kWh/1000h on the box; what does that mean?

Tags: led, power-consumption, lamp

I bought a LED bulb for my room which uses 8.2 W power = 60 W conventional. I know this means it's a 8.2 W LED bulb which gives a brightness equivalent to a 60 W incandescent bulb.

[image]

So here it says 9 kWh/1000h. From what I understand this means that if you use the bulb for a 1000 hours it will consume 9 kWh of power. If the electric company charges, say, 52p/kWh and I run the LED for 1000 hours, it will cost me 9 x 52p = 468p = £4.68. Am I right?

Comment: Generally you are right, but i have a question. Don't you have to use multipliers like 3, 4, 12 between GBP, feet, pints and other British units?

Comment: @TQQQ British currency was decimalized many years ago. Feet, pints, etc. are a different situation, but the only things here are kWh, hours (1kWh = 1 kW x 1 hour or 1 W x 1,000 hours) and currency.

Comment: I don’t think so we are simply just multiplying per kwh cost to the total energy units consume we get our answer in pence which we then convert to GBP by dividing it by 100 as 1 pound = 100 pence.

Comment: They rounded the 8.2W up to 9W. I wonder if there is some legal implication (as in possible liability)  to the energy cost claim (as in they could be sued in a class-action suit for 10^6 bulbs using 0.3W more than advertised).

Comment: It was a joke. Your calculation is correct. Just note, that 9W is a rounded value (probably for the sake of the A+ marking) and that actual power may slightly vary. ANd to be absolutely correct, nothing is like measurement - with the Chinese LEDs you never know, it may be in fact 3W with less light, or 18W with same light.

Comment: @TQQQ Eveready is an old (founded in 1896 as the American Electrical Novelty and Manufacturing Company) American company, though I'm sure the bulbs are made in China or thereabouts.

Comment: I am pretty sure that unless it's Philipps or Osram, it's safe to say we have no idea what's actually there :)

Comment: @Spehro it might just be Power Factor too.

Answer (score 3):

It means it uses 9kWh for 1000 hours of use.

Energy efficiency is often written in kWh because that's the unit on the electricity bill.

So your calculation is correct: 1000 hours will cost 9 x £0.52 = £4.68.

For sense check: of course 1,000 hours of an (approximately) 9W device will use 9,000 Wh, or 9 kWh.

Comment: So the power cost calculation i did is right?

Comment: You did.  But strictly speaking, it's an _energy_ cost calculation.

Comment: Oh yes  didn’t know what to call it exactly. Appreciated.

Comment: This is another way of writing 9 watts :)

Comment: @user253751 Yes, it is, in this particular case. But these energy labels are universal and the kWh consumption figure also includes the typical duty cycle. So the kWh/year listed for a fridge will be much less than what you get if you just multiply the rated power in watts by the number of hours in a year.